# Custom SMTP server - works with all except outlook

Tags: email, outlook, smtp

I'm building a simple SMTP **server** that listens on port 25, responds 250 Ok to everything and accepts all mail that's coming in:

```
Connected: ::ffff:209.85.166.174
< 220 XXXX.XXX.AU running experimental mail server
> EHLO mail-il1-f174.google.com
< 250-xxxx.xxx.au
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250 Ok
> MAIL FROM:<xxxxx.xxxxx@gmail.com>
< 250 OK
> RCPT TO:<xxxx.xxx@xxxx.xxx.au>
< 250 OK
> DATA

< 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
> Received: by mail-il1-f174.google.com with SMTP id ........
...
```

Works with every incoming mail except if it's from Microsoft/Outlook. If it's outlook, it connects but sends nothing, no EHLO, no MAIL FROM, just connects and sits there until connection times out. What is it waiting for?

```
Connected: ::ffff:40.92.52.87
< 220 XXXX.XXX.AU running experimental mail server
< 451 4.4.2 Timeout waiting for data from client.
```